# Manage/Assign Roles to Users Other than Administrators

Tags: 6, users

I was asked to create a module that allows a user with the specific role to assign roles to other users w/no 'administer user' permissions or not an administrator. The user must not be allowed to edit info about the users with 'administer user' permission/admin.

How can I do this? Do I have to create a custom module for this? Is it possible to use Views module for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** Since Drupal 6 is [un-supported now](https://www.drupal.org/about/drupal6-eol) (check [announcement](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-6-eol)), you won't get a module which still have the D6 version actively supported. Also don't expect the module to be supported for any issues.

You can check the [Role Delegation](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_delegation) module, which allow users to set user roles to other user. Following is the module description from module page:

> This module allows site administrators to grant specific roles the
>   authority to assign selected roles to users, without them needing the
>   administer permissions permission.

The last release of this module for Drupal 6 version was made available on 9 Dec 2010, you can download it from [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_delegation/releases/6.x-1.4).

Comment: Thank you but Can this be achieved through Views?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can create a user list view with [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) and try allowing user to change user role in user listing.